# Submitting an app for review and then removed it to make changes to the app from Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm changing some stuff for my app from Xcode after I removed it from review, because there were stuff that I needed to change; do I have to go to archive and distribute the app again and redo everything for the app information and then I would submit it ?

Comment: Yes, archive, upload, submit. But no need to redo the app info though you can edit it if needed.

Comment: thank you a lot, but they would show this when I intend to distribute -("Redundant Binary Upload. You've already uploaded a build with build number '1' for version number '1.0'. Make sure you increment the build string before you upload your app to App Store Connect)

Comment: Right. You need to do what is says and increment the build number before you archive. The build number of every archive must be different.

Comment: so I just have to change the version number right?

Comment: The build version, not the app version.

Comment: oh I got what you mean the build right. thank you so much Maddy you are a very valuable person <3.